# Getting : element not interactable when using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to click Load More button with Selenium. Though I'm getting the `Message: element not interactable` error.
When I save the HTML response loaded by Selenium and open in as HTML I see the button is there and it is clickable ( see image below).
Also here is a button tag from this saved page:

```
<kcl-load-more main-class="mb-25" on-click="addMorePosts()" model="latestPosts" model-loading="postsLoading" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<div class="kcl-load-more mb-25" ng-class="vm.mainClass">\n\n
    <!-- ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf -->
    <button class="kcl-btn ng-scope" ng-class="vm.buttonClass" ng-click="vm.click()" ng-disabled="vm.loading || vm.modelLoading" ng-if="vm.model.length &amp;&amp; !vm.hideIf" style="">\n <span class="hidden-side-scroll">LOAD MORE</span>\n
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 35.09 34.39" height="32" width="32" aria-labelledby="title" class="icon visible-side-scroll">\n
            <title>Load More</title>\n
            <path fill="#3B3B3B" d="M35.09,17.19s0-.09,0-.13h0a1.31,1.31,0,0,0-.38-.78l0,0L18.82.38A1.31,1.31,0,0,0,17,2.23L30.62,15.88H1.31a1.31,1.31,0,0,0,0,2.62H30.62L17,32.15A1.31,1.31,0,1,0,18.82,34L34.67,18.15l0,0a1.31,1.31,0,0,0,.38-.79h0s0-.09,0-.14Z"></path>\n </svg>\n </button>
    <!-- end ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf -->\n
    <!-- ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf -->
    <div class="visible-side-scroll text-center ng-scope" ng-if="vm.model.length &amp;&amp; !vm.hideIf" ng-click="vm.click()" style="">LOAD MORE</div>
    <!-- end ngIf: vm.model.length && !vm.hideIf -->\n</div>\n</kcl-load-more>
```

[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
from selenium import webdriver      
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

URL = "https://thekrazycouponlady.com/coupons-for/costco"
LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH = '//button[@class = "kcl-btn ng-scope"]' 
# ADD_XPATH = '//button[@class = "btn btn-dismiss holiday-dismiss"]'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Python3\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get(URL)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(35)
        html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
        print(html)

        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH)
        loadMoreButton.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        break
print ("Complete")

driver.quit()
```

How do I click the button?

P.S. Full exception log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Active\driverv1.py", line 10, in <module>
    wd.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-class='vm.buttonClass']").click()
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <button class="kcl-btn ng-scope" ng-class="vm.buttonClass" ng-click="vm.click()" ng-disabled="vm.loading || vm.modelLoading" ng-if="vm.model.length &amp;&amp; !vm.hideIf" style="">...</button> is not clickable at point (511, 686). Other element would receive the click: <iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/4916285/sdb_tabbot_728x90.01_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/4916285/sdb_tabbot_728x90.01_0" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" srcdoc="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google-container-id="1" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)
```

Comment: @DebanjanB This is different question. The question you refer to is different one and it was answered. You did not show enough attention on that question posting irrelevant comment and now you close this question as duplicate. Please Undo.

Comment: Try using find_element_by_css_selector. This will work for you.

    from selenium import webdriver[new line]
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)[new line]
    URL = "https://thekrazycouponlady.com/coupons-for/costco"[new line]
    wd.get(URL)[new line]
    wd.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-class='vm.buttonClass']").click()[new line]

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar This did not help. Getting the very same error message.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar  I commented on his decision above. To no avile.

Comment: @BillyJhon , add full exception log. Also check whether `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(LOAD_MORE_BUTTON_XPATH)))` returns `1`

Comment: @Andersson Exception added. Yes, it returns 1.

Comment: I could have helped you with the code but since it is closed I coul'nt. The problem is that whenever that page is opened by headless chrome. A pop up is apearing in the page which needs to be closed first. And then you can use the code I provided above. You can check that without using headless one and using a browser enabled selenium.

Comment: @BillyJhon , the button seem to be covered by google-ads frame. Did you try to close/remove it before click?

Comment: @Andersson I do not see how to close the iframe. I see there is a baloon add on the page so i tried to close it using this xpath - ADD_XPATH = '//button[@class = "btn btn-dismiss holiday-dismiss"]'  Still got the same error.

Comment: So when you click button matched by `ADD_XPATH` the add modal window is not closed or closed but you still cannot click target button? You might need to wait for modal to be completely closed (invisible) before clicking

Comment: @Andersson  I can manually close the add and click Load More button in the window opened by selenium. After the code has executed and thrown exception ( i have removed close driver from code for that )

Comment: If you can do this manually, then you should be able to do this automatically, but I cannot navigate to shared URL, so it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is too heavy and takes too much time to load. I have tried writing an optimal code for your problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
URL = "https://thekrazycouponlady.com/coupons-for/costco"
chrome_path = r"chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
wd.get(URL)
```

Wait until the pop up appears and when it does close it. You can also first try to scrape the contents and meanwhile if pop up appears close it but that will become a little bit complicated.

```
while(True):
    try:
        wd.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='btn btn-dismiss holiday-dismiss']").click()
        break
    except:
        continue
```

Execute these three lines in a loop for loading the "LOAD MORE" contents, give delay of atmost 2s for each execution.

```
element = wd.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='newsletter-sign-up-widget']")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
wd.find_element_by_css_selector("button[ng-class='vm.buttonClass']").click()
```

P.S : I have also tried it using headless chrome on google-colab. Comment below if you need the notebook for headless one on cloud.